# Add image into a word .docx document header using Apache POI XWPF

Tags: image, header, apache-poi

Can anyone please help me to add image into word document (.docx) header using Apache POI's XWPF component?

Comment: What kind of Word file are you working on? .doc with HWPF, or .docx with XWPF?

Comment: I am working on XWPF .docx document.

Answer (score -1):

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/images/image.png"); 
XWPFParagraph par1 = doc.createParagraph();
XWPFRun runAppName = par1.createRun();  
runAppName.addPicture(fis, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "image.png", 257, 185);

doc.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("/folder/document.docx")));
```

Comment: This adds a picture in the document body, but not in the header.