# Add an image to an XWPFDocument using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have tried adding an image to the header of an XWPFDocument with no success. I am using Apache POI.

Here is what I am currently using as a solution:

**Header creation**

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(docxInputStream));
CTP headerCtp = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
CTR headerCtr = headerCtp.addNewR();

XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(headerCtp, document);
XWPFRun run = headerParagraph.getRun(headerCtr);
InputStream pictureInputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\logo.jpg");
run.addPicture(pictureInputStream, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "logo.jpg", 300, 150);
pictureInputStream.close();
run.addTab();
run.setText(contentName);

setTabStop(headerCtp, STTabJc.Enum.forString("right"), BigInteger.valueOf(9000));

XWPFParagraph[] headerParagraphs = {headerParagraph};
CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document, sectPr);
headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(STHdrFtr.DEFAULT, headerParagraphs);
```

**setTabStop method**

```
private static void setTabStop(CTP oCTP, STTabJc.Enum oSTTabJc, BigInteger oPos) {
    CTPPr oPPr = oCTP.getPPr();
    if (oPPr == null) {
        oPPr = oCTP.addNewPPr();
    }

    CTTabs oTabs = oPPr.getTabs();
    if (oTabs == null) {
        oTabs = oPPr.addNewTabs();
    }

    CTTabStop oTabStop = oTabs.addNewTab();
    oTabStop.setVal(oSTTabJc);
    oTabStop.setPos(oPos);
}
```

The trouble I am having is that the image is loaded in the run, meaning the size of the pictures array is 1, however it isn't getting displayed in the document.

I have tried numerous solutions such as the following ones:

[Add image into a word .docx document header using Apache POI XWPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235868/add-image-into-a-word-docx-document-header-using-apache-poi-xwpf)

[how to add a picture to a .docx document with Apache POI XWPF in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674115/how-to-add-a-picture-to-a-docx-document-with-apache-poi-xwpf-in-java)

[Java - POI - Add a picture to the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645062/java-poi-add-a-picture-to-the-header)

[How i can add an Image as my header in a word document using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583478/how-i-can-add-an-image-as-my-header-in-a-word-document-using-apache-poi)

Any hints and ideas as to what I may be doing wrong are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Apache POI? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I am using version 3.11.

Comment: Which as shown [on the Apache POI download page](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) is by no means the latest... What happens, as already said, when you upgrade?

Comment: I've updated to 3.13, but to no avail. The image is still not getting displayed.

Comment: Read about POI-scratchpad